# Assign feature layer properties assigned to counties to a division ( group of counties)

Tags: javascript, arcgis, esri, arcgis-js-api

Below written code highlights a county when a mouse is moved on to a particular county. I want to highlight the entire division(set of counties) when the mouse is moved on to any county of that particular division..

```
map = new Map("mapDiv", {
          basemap: "streets",
          center: [-96.921387,36.084621],
          zoom: 8,
          slider: false
        });

        var oklahomaCounties = new FeatureLayer("http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Demographics/ESRI_Census_USA/MapServer/3", 
        {
          //mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_SNAPSHOT,
          outFields: ["NAME"]
       });
        oklahomaCounties.setDefinitionExpression("STATE_NAME = 'Oklahoma'");
```

Comment: I want to highlight the entire division when the mouse is moved on to any county of that particular division.... Please help me and thanks in adavnce

Comment: Can anyone help me with this issue..??

Comment: Can you share the complete code?
I mean where are you adding "oklahomaCounties " to the map and where are you adding feature layer events to it.

Answer (score 0):

I found a sample I guess it's seems similar to your need.

http://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/sandbox/sandbox.html?sample=fl_hover

Hope this will help you :)

If you need working solution please share exact code where your are facing issue.

> Edited:

Based on below discussion below are the steps to achieve it.
We have two way to achieve it.

**First Approach:**

Onhover; I fetch all the division records from given layer and add it to the map but this will cause you performance issue like after hovering you have to wait utill you get all the records.

**Second Approach**

Initially on load of app get all records from above layer, this will be one time activity; process the output data/features and create collection in such a manner so that key will be division name and features push to its specific division. once you are ready with collection then simply on hover which ever feature you are getting first find from which group/division its belonging and highlight all the feature from that division on the map.

I would recommend to go with this because it will not fetch every time data; only first load time will increased a little bit.

Let me know if any clarifications required.

Comment: I am using the same code which is in the link you gave me. Instead of highlighting a single county when the mouse is hovered, I want to highlight group of counties together i.e for example highlight 3 counties ( say Cimarron,Texas and Beaver which comes under division-1) at the same time when the mouse is hovered on any of the single county from those 3 counties.

Comment: I am not sure where exactly to modify the code to highlight group of counties? please help if you can

Comment: Do you have any other "division" layer?
Can you simply tell me on which besis you want to highlight.

Comment: Do you have any specific business logic for this create or filter group of boundaries?
Because filtering or higlighting of graphics one or more is not a big deal... just wanted to indentify the logic behind this.

Comment: or if its simple POC then let me know the layer and array/collection of groups

Comment: I don't have any division layer, i have to create it based on division code.

Comment: Oklahoma have 77 counties and are divided into 8 divisions. Each division have a division code starting from 1 to 8. for example Adair
Cherokee
Haskell
McIntosh
Muskogee
Okmulgee
Sequoyah
Wagoner

Comment: the above mentioned counties come under division-1. can you tell me how to highlight all the counties of a division when the mouse is hovered on any county of that division. if you can tell me for division, I can proceed from there. thank you

Comment: I have a database with counties, divisions and division code as fields. If you can tell me for one county, i can proceed from there..

Comment: Thank you and do you got any idea...?

Comment: i have solution i am just not getting time to create poc... will get bback to u soon

Comment: while creating this; I am assuming you have predefine set of divisions like: division1 = [Adair Cherokee Haskell McIntosh Muskogee Okmulgee Sequoyah Wagoner]
division2 = [abc, def, ghi, jkl]..  and so on...
i dont have exact divisions to i have to make first groups.. so its taking time...

Comment: one more thing @Santosh you have posted one more question on stackoverflow related to arcgis js api.. why you are not responding on that?

Comment: yes vikash, your assumption is right about the predefined set of counties, if you could help me for one division, i can do it for the remaining 7 divisions.

Comment: for my previous question, i got to know how to access the County name outside the template box. Thank you

Comment: I am waiting for your answer vikash... please try to help me

Comment: Can you do it ... Vikash

Comment: @Santosh: i am a little busy during these day..i will post answere asap... do one thing atleast you start with 2nd approach and let me know where exactly you are stuck...  simply you can send me updated or inprogress at vikash2402@gmail.com